# Changing the `sd` of a `dnorm` used in `outer` in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix

I was wondering if I could add a `sd = 2` in the `dnorm()` that I have used in my `outer()` in the R code below?

```
  mu = seq(178 - 3 * 20, 178 + 3 * 20, by = 5)
   y = seq(min(mu) - 3 * 2, max(mu) + 3 * 2, by = 1)

cond = outer(y, mu, dnorm) ## Here the `dnorm` is using the default `sd = 1`.
                           ## Could the default `sd` be changed to `2`?
```

Comment: Please study help("outer"). Pay special attention to the ellipses argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  Just use   `cond = outer(y, mu, dnorm, sd=2)`

```
args(outer)
function (X, Y, FUN = "*", ...)
```

The ... means that any additional arguments are passed into the function, in this case `dnorm`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because you can pass optional arguments to the function you use. Like so:

```
mu = seq(178 - 3 * 20, 178 + 3 * 20, by = 5)
y = seq(min(mu) - 3 * 2, max(mu) + 3 * 2, by = 1)

cond = outer(y, mu, dnorm, sd = 2)
```

This is also explained on the help page `?outer` btw.